# Excel-VBA : search for cell with specific time value

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    Dim i As Integer, TimeValueToFind As Date
    TimeValueToFind = "00:00:00"
    Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To 25   '
        If Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value = TimeValueToFind Then
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)

            Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").Value = Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 1).Resize(1).Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

This code checks Column A for the time inputted in the format xx:xx:xx Both where the input is, and where the times are written are set as "Time" format

There is a table with times in from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00 in Column A.
For some reason, this code will only work when trying to find 00:00:00, no other time value is found at all. I can't figure out the reason why.
I thought it might be because TimeValueToFind is "as Date". However there seems to be no "As Time" though? Unsure why this is not working. And if that's the case why it doesn't work, why is 00:00:00 found but nothing else? It's a simple error I bet but some help would be greatly appreciated.

For additional information:

Tidal Time is Column A.

```
Tidal Time  Tidal Height
00:00:00    
01:00:00    
02:00:00    
03:00:00    
04:00:00    4.40
05:00:00    4.00
06:00:00    3.60
07:00:00    3.20
08:00:00    2.80
09:00:00    2.40
10:00:00    2.00
11:00:00    2.37
12:00:00    2.74
13:00:00    3.11
14:00:00    3.49
15:00:00    3.86
16:00:00    4.23
17:00:00    4.60
18:00:00    4.13
19:00:00    3.67
20:00:00    3.20
21:00:00    2.73
22:00:00    2.27
23:00:00    1.80
```

The Entirity of Column A is Time. Now It's important to understand that for awhile now I've been punching myself in the face as for i to 25 should have been 2 to 25, the String Tidal Height is incorrect format and this was the reason for the missmatch error.

Comment: Check if IsDate(cell like 00:00:00) returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to compare apples and oranges.
`TimeValueToFind` is of type `Date` and `Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value` yields a `double` (add both to the watches window and check).

You can make it work either by converting `TimeValueToFind` to a `double` or casting `Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value` to a `Date`:

```
' (...)
If CDate(Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value) = TimeValueToFind Then
' (...)
```

Or:

```
' (...)
delta = Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value - CDbl(TimeValueToFind)
If Abs(delta) <= tolerance Then
' (...)
```

Comment: Hm with CDate I get type missmatch error. And converting TimeValueToFind to CDbl does not find the time value inputted either because of the tolerance, just a thing to note

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the double's lack of precision as you (and others) noted. Old habits die hard... As for the type mismatch, it may be related to the format of your cell's value since the `CDate` function takes into account your regional settings when converting.

Comment: Seem to be getting a type missmatch error on the double one now too. my code looks like that: `Sub FindMatchingValue()  
    Dim i As Integer,   TimeValueToFind As Date  
    TimeValueToFind = "04:00:00"  
    Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").ClearContents  
    For i = 1 To 25    
        Delta = Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value - CDbl  (TimeValueToFind)  
        If Abs(Delta) <= tolerance Then
` Delta line is highlighted. The cells in question are all "Time"

Comment: Got no errors here... can you post a sample of your inputs?

Comment: Also, if you have `Option Explicit`, did you declare (`Dim`) both `Delta` and `tolerance`? Those are not type mismatches but compile errors, but check anyway.

Comment: Okay sorted the mismatch error it was because I had a text header and the i was 1-25 not 2-25. If still never runs if. 04:00:00 is for sure in column "A"

Comment: Or am I supposed to declare tolerance as something? I just wrote it like `If Abs(Delta) <= tolerance Then ` if I change the value to 00:00:00 it finds the value on row 2. any other number it doesn't find

Comment: You have to declare both `delta` and `tolerance` (as you did with `i` and `TimeValueToFind`) and assign a value to `tolerance`. Declaring both as `double` and assigning `0.001` to `tolerance` will find `04:00:00` in row `6` (and any other whole hours). `tolerance` is a number up to which we consider two doubles as having the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores times as fractions of a day.  So hour 00:00:00 is 0/24ths of a day.  Hour 01:00:00 is 1/24th of a day or .041666, etc.  You need to compare against those values.  If you test the value in column `A` you will see it is a number from 0 to 1.  If you run something like this you can see what's happening.

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Test As Variant

For i = 1 To 24
    Test = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Test
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Excel stores numbers as a `double`. It is well known that the expression `a==b` is likely to return `False` when `a` and `b` are both doubles, even though you might *think* they are the same. This is due to the finite precision with which floating point numbers are stored.

You have various options.

1) Set a tolerance. `If abs(a-b)<tolerance Then`

2) Convert to a string with a fixed number of digits, and compare the strings. This is doing explicitly what the above does implicitly

The first approach is usually considered the way to go. You should ban testing for equality from your vocabulary when you are using floating point numbers.